# Freeform Pro 4.1.3 install question

Tags: solspace-freeform

I installed Freeform Pro 4.1.3 but it does not appear in the "modules" area of the control panel. I copied the files twice and checked their location but still no change appeared in the "modules" area of the control panel.

I'm running EE2.6.1, PHP 5.4.7 and MySQL Server 5.5

Any idea what may cause the module not to appear?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the module doesn't show up in the list, it's most definitely not in the right place. Are you sure the third_party config override isn't in place, pointing EE to another directory for add-ons? This is a fairly common scenario.

Comment: I haven't changed any configurations and other add-ons are showing up that have been placed in the same two directories.

Comment: I'm running EE2.6.1, PHP 5.4.7 and MySQL Server 5.5 on IIS  using a Windows Server. Is Freeform Pro compatible with the Windows Server?